# Summation and Subtraction of Vector Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U, W$ be vector subspaces of V, such that $U, W \leq V$.

Let $U-W = \left \{ u-w \;|\;  u \in U, w \in W \right \}$

In this case, is $U+W = U-W$? I'm guessing yes because subtraction in this sense is just addition with a negative direction. Am I right in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right: let $v \in U - W$, then $v = u - w$, $u \in U$ and $w \in W$.
But it is also true that $v = U + W$ being $u \in U$ and $-w \in W$. Therefore $U - W \subset U + W$. The other inclusion follows in the same way.

Comment: in that sense, $U-W$ would then be defined as a vector subspace of $V$ too?

Comment: @mercurial, you cannot «define something as a vector subspace of $V$»: being a subspaace of $V$ is a *property* a subset of $V$ can have or not.

Comment: Oops okay I meant in this case $U-W$ would then be a vector subspace of $V$

Comment: yes, it is! checking is very easy: you need to keep n mind that both $U$ and $W$ are subspaces.